# Nested object access parents attribute

Tags: java, android

I'm kinda new at Java and I have a simple question. In the code below:

```
conversation.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long arg3) {          
            if (adapter.getItem(position).image && adapter.getItem(position).left) {
                String imgName = ((Message)arg1.findViewById(R.id.imageUploaded).getTag()).message;
                try {
                    AlertDialog.Builder confirmQuit = new AlertDialog.Builder(Chat.this);
                    confirmQuit.setMessage("Download image?");

                    // Buttons on dialog
                    confirmQuit.setPositiveButton("Download", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                        }
                    });
                    confirmQuit.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            // Do nothing
                        }
                    });
                    confirmQuit.create();

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        }
    });
}
```

That's an android code and I would like to know how can I access the variables `position` and `imgName` inside the `DialogInterface.OnClickListener`?

Usually in these cases I create a "global" private variable as an attribute on my activity so I can access it anywhere, but it doesn't seem right. Can someone help?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change

```
String imgName = ...
```

to

```
final String imgName = ...
```

From the Java Tutorial for [Anonymous Classes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html#accessing):

> **Accessing Local Variables of the Enclosing Scope**
>
> Like local classes, anonymous classes can capture variables; they have
>   the same access to local variables of the enclosing scope:
>
> - An anonymous class has access to the members of its enclosing class.
> - An anonymous class *cannot access local variables in its enclosing    scope that are not declared as final* or effectively final.

Comment: I feel stupid .-.
Gonna read about final attributes. Thanks man. :)

Comment: @JoãoMenighin edited the answer for more details. hope it's useful :)