# How to Allow Shared Preferences Inside OnClick to Resolve to a Variable

Tags: android, string, android-intent, sharedpreferences, oncreate

I am trying to make it so that clicking an item on the action bar saves text using shared preferences. However, the strings must be generated in the OnCreate of the app or that leads the app to crash. But you can't put a method inside the On Create, so the shared preferences inside the onOptionItemSelected or the OnClick cannot find the strings in the app. I know this sounds really confusing, so if you need clarification just ask.

Here is the code

```
    package com.bernard.beaconportal;

    import java.lang.reflect.Field;

   import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragment;
import com.actionbarsherlock.view.Menu;
import com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuInflater;
import com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuItem;
import com.astuetz.PagerSlidingTabStrip;
import com.bernard.beaconportal.FragmentsLinked.ViewPagerAdapterScheduleView;

import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;

    public class FragmentsEdit extends FragmentActivity {

        private ViewPager pager;
        private ViewPagerAdapterSchedule adapter;
        private PagerSlidingTabStrip tabs;
        String uriString;






        @Override
            public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
             super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
             getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);







             setContentView(R.layout.viewpager_schedule);

             pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPager1);

             adapter = new ViewPagerAdapterSchedule(getSupportFragmentManager());

             tabs = (PagerSlidingTabStrip) findViewById(R.id.pagerTabStrip1);

             pager.setAdapter(adapter);

             tabs.setViewPager(pager);


             Intent intents = getIntent();

                String GFriday = intents.getStringExtra("G_Friday");
                String BFriday = intents.getStringExtra("B_Friday");
                String ADV1Friday = intents.getStringExtra("ADV1_Friday");
                String ADV2Friday = intents.getStringExtra("ADV2_Friday");
                String CFriday = intents.getStringExtra("C_Friday");
                String FFriday = intents.getStringExtra("F_Friday");







                Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.menu.android_apply);

                button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(View view){


                                 SharedPreferences sharedPref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("schedule",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
                                    editor.putString("G_Friday", GFriday);
                                    editor.putString("B_Friday", BFriday);
                                    editor.putString("ADV1_Friday", ADV1Friday);
                                    editor.putString("ADV2_Friday", ADV2Friday);
                                    editor.putString("C_Friday", CFriday);
                                    editor.putString("F_Friday", FFriday);
                                    editor.commit();

                            }


                        });


        }







         public class ViewPagerAdapterSchedule extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

                // Declare the number of ViewPager pages
                final int PAGE_COUNT = 5;
                private String titles[] = new String[] { "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday" };

                public ViewPagerAdapterSchedule(FragmentManager fm) {
                    super(fm);
                }

                @Override
                public Fragment getItem(int position) {
                    switch (position) {

                        // Open FragmentTab1.java
                    case 0:
                        Monday schedule_list_view = new Monday();
                        return schedule_list_view;

                        // Open FragmentTab2.java
                    case 1:
                        Tuesday schedule_list_view1 = new Tuesday();
                        return schedule_list_view1;

                    case 2:
                        Wednesday schedule_list_view2 = new Wednesday();
                        return schedule_list_view2;

                    case 3:
                        Thursday schedule_list_view3 = new Thursday();
                        return schedule_list_view3;

                    case 4:
                        Friday schedule_list_view4 = new Friday();
                        return schedule_list_view4;
                    }
                    return null;
                }

                public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
                    return titles[position];
                }

                @Override
                public int getCount() {
                    return PAGE_COUNT;
                }




        }








    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(android.view.Menu menu) {

            android.view.MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
              inflater.inflate(R.menu.android_apply, menu);


           return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

    }

    @Override
           public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(android.view.MenuItem item) {
               // Handle presses on the action bar items
               switch (item.getItemId()) {
                   case R.id.apply:



                       Intent in = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
                       startActivity(in);

                       return true;
                   default:
                       return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);


    }



    }



    }
```

And here I try to do everything using OnOptionsItemSelected

```
 package com.bernard.beaconportal;

    import java.lang.reflect.Field;

   import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragment;
import com.actionbarsherlock.view.Menu;
import com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuInflater;
import com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuItem;
import com.astuetz.PagerSlidingTabStrip;
import com.bernard.beaconportal.FragmentsLinked.ViewPagerAdapterScheduleView;

import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;

    public class FragmentsEdit extends FragmentActivity {

        private ViewPager pager;
        private ViewPagerAdapterSchedule adapter;
        private PagerSlidingTabStrip tabs;
        String uriString;






        @Override
            public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
             super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
             getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);







             setContentView(R.layout.viewpager_schedule);

             pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPager1);

             adapter = new ViewPagerAdapterSchedule(getSupportFragmentManager());

             tabs = (PagerSlidingTabStrip) findViewById(R.id.pagerTabStrip1);

             pager.setAdapter(adapter);

             tabs.setViewPager(pager);


             Intent intents = getIntent();

                String GFriday = intents.getStringExtra("G_Friday");
                String BFriday = intents.getStringExtra("B_Friday");
                String ADV1Friday = intents.getStringExtra("ADV1_Friday");
                String ADV2Friday = intents.getStringExtra("ADV2_Friday");
                String CFriday = intents.getStringExtra("C_Friday");
                String FFriday = intents.getStringExtra("F_Friday");



        }







         public class ViewPagerAdapterSchedule extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

                // Declare the number of ViewPager pages
                final int PAGE_COUNT = 5;
                private String titles[] = new String[] { "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday" };

                public ViewPagerAdapterSchedule(FragmentManager fm) {
                    super(fm);
                }

                @Override
                public Fragment getItem(int position) {
                    switch (position) {

                        // Open FragmentTab1.java
                    case 0:
                        Monday schedule_list_view = new Monday();
                        return schedule_list_view;

                        // Open FragmentTab2.java
                    case 1:
                        Tuesday schedule_list_view1 = new Tuesday();
                        return schedule_list_view1;

                    case 2:
                        Wednesday schedule_list_view2 = new Wednesday();
                        return schedule_list_view2;

                    case 3:
                        Thursday schedule_list_view3 = new Thursday();
                        return schedule_list_view3;

                    case 4:
                        Friday schedule_list_view4 = new Friday();
                        return schedule_list_view4;
                    }
                    return null;
                }

                public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
                    return titles[position];
                }

                @Override
                public int getCount() {
                    return PAGE_COUNT;
                }




        }








    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(android.view.Menu menu) {

            android.view.MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
              inflater.inflate(R.menu.android_apply, menu);


           return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

    }

    @Override
           public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(android.view.MenuItem item) {
               // Handle presses on the action bar items
               switch (item.getItemId()) {
                   case R.id.apply:

                       SharedPreferences sharedPref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("schedule",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
                        editor.putString("G_Friday", GFriday);
                        editor.putString("B_Friday", BFriday);
                        editor.putString("ADV1_Friday", ADV1Friday);
                        editor.putString("ADV2_Friday", ADV2Friday);
                        editor.putString("C_Friday", CFriday);
                        editor.putString("F_Friday", FFriday);
                        editor.commit();

                       Intent in = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
                       startActivity(in);

                       return true;
                   default:
                       return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);


    }



    }



    }
```

Comment: Just a comment, your variables should begin with a lowerCase letter, so they are not confused with Class names.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Nested object access parents attribute](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23819508/nested-object-access-parents-attribute)

Comment: different because I use OnOptionItemSelected, which means the stuff contained by that cannot see the Strings that are inside the onCreate even if they're final.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can declare your `String` variables globally , like you are doing with `uriString` , like this:

```
private String gFriday,bFriday,aDV1Friday,aDV2Friday, cFriday, fFriday;
```

Then, inside `onCreate()`, you attribute a value to them, like you are already doing:

```
gFriday = intents.getStringExtra("G_Friday");
bFriday = intents.getStringExtra("B_Friday");
aADV1Friday = intents.getStringExtra("ADV1_Friday");
aDV2Friday = intents.getStringExtra("ADV2_Friday");
cFriday = intents.getStringExtra("C_Friday");
fFriday = intents.getStringExtra("F_Friday");
```

This way, your scope is not limited to `onCreate()` method and you can access your String from inside `onOptionsItemSelected().`

Answer (score 1):

I think the 6 Strings you want to save should be in an array and declared as a field, and the keys should be declared as constants (for a cleaner code and to solve your scope issue).

```
public class FragmentsEdit extends FragmentActivity {
    public static final String[] myKeys = { 
        "G_Friday", "B_Friday", "ADV1_Friday", 
        "ADV2_Friday", "C_Friday", "F_Friday" 
    };
    private List<String> myDayList;

    ...

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        myDayList = new ArrayList<String>();

        Intent intent = getIntent();

        if (intent != null) // don't forget to test it
        {
            for ( String curKey : myKeys )
                myDayList.add(intent.getStringExtra(curKey));
        }

        ....
    }
```

Now you can save it anywhere using this method :

```
    public void savePref() {
        SharedPreferences sharedPref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("schedule",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();

        int i = 0;

        for (String curStr : myDayList)
            if (i < myKeys.length) // to be sure we are not out of bound
                editor.putString(myKeys[i++], curStr);

        editor.commit();

    }
```

That should do the trick. I haven't tested it so there may be errors